# N number of Sequelize connections to dynamically query via API calls

Tags: node.js, database, api, express, sequelize.js

I'm looking to get some opinions on what the best approach is for the following scenario:

Our product requires connections to our users' Postgres databases via our Node Express server, they provide their credentials once and we store it in an encrypted way in our internal operations DB and can reference to it when access is needed. A user can do an action on our app UI like create a table, delete a table, etc. and view table sizes, min max values of a column, etc.

These actions comes to our server as authenticated API calls and we can query their databases via Sequelize as needed and return the results to frontend.

My question is, when there are N number of users with N number of databases from different SQL instances that need to be connected when an API is called to query the respective database, what is the best approach to maintain that?

Should we create a new Sequelize connection instance each time an API is called and run the query, return the response, and close the connection. Or create a new Sequelize connection instance for a DB when an API is called, and keep the instance for certain amount of time, and close the connection if it was inactive during that amount of time, and restart the instance next time?

If there are better and more efficient ways of doing this, I would love to hear about it. Thanks.

Currently, I've tried to do a new Sequelize instance each time at the beginning of the API request, and run the query, and then close the connection. Works ok, but that's just locally with 2 DBs so I can't tell what production would be like.

Edit: Anatoly suggested connection pool, in that case, what're the things that need to be considered for the config?

Comment: Please look at connection pool options in Sequelize, maybe it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly, I've edited my question on that. Sorry, the docs on connection pool in Sequelize are quite bare and I'm too sure on the ideal config.